# wpf is not updating textblock text and image source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to change my image source and some text in a textblock, the source comes from a class that is returned from a WCF service and is in a String format, when i use some functions in my code, images and text will update, but if i try to update it right before a Thread.Sleep it won't change, same for the textblock

Here's the problematic code:

```
            //ris is the class returned from the server
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Res/" + ris.carta + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            if (ris.IDv == ID)
            {
                puntiuno += ris.punti;
                txtb_info.Text += "\nHai vinto la mano!";
                mano.Add(ricevicarte(2)[0]);
                V = true;
            }
            else
            {
                txtb_info.Text += "\nHai perso la mano!";
                puntidue += ris.punti;
                mano.Add(ricevicarte(2)[0]);
                V = false;
            }
            //Secondacarta(ris.carta);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            aggiornainterfaccia();
            txtb_info.Text += "\nNuova mano!";
            blocco = 0;
```

everything that comes after the Thread.Sleep works, every WPF controls update i try before won't work

Here's the "aggiornainterfaccia()" code:

```
private void aggiornainterfaccia()
    {
        ris = null;            
        carta1_img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Res/" + mano[0] + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        carta2_img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Res/" + mano[1] + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        carta3_img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Res/" + mano[2] + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Res/dorso.png", UriKind.Relative));
        txt_punti_p1.Text = "Punti: " + puntiuno.ToString();
        txt_punti_p2.Text = "Punti: " + puntidue.ToString();
        txtb_info.Text = "";
        if (V)
        {
            lbl_mano.Content = "Sei di mano!";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_mano.Content = "Non sei di mano!";
        }
    }
```

this is called right after the delay and it works and its function is to reset  the interface to a initial state

Comment: If you execute `Thread.Sleep()` in UI thread, then you are blocking UI from update. In other words any change you did to it before sleeping will never appears on screen. There are multiple ways to solve the issue, `async/await Task.Delay()` might be the simplest, but consider to move your *long running job* into another thread and rather invoke results of it into UI thread.

Comment: maybe, i haven't understood your comment, but the thread.sleep() works as a dealyer between two hands of trump card game, i need to update a card and then "block" the execution of the main thread in order to show results to players

Comment: Don't sleep in UI thread. This is blocking UI from repainting itself (tha problem you have experienced), interacting with user, etc. As a quick fix: replace it with `await Task.Delay(5000)` (mark event handler as `async`, no worry - compiler will warn you about this). You can read more about async/await, but as I said earlier, rather study the subject of how to run long job without freezing UI: `BackgroundWorker`, `Task`/`Thread` + `Invoke`. In simpler case to organize *awaiting* between short UI updates you can use `Timer`.

Comment: add this as answer, so i can mark the question as answered